# How do I remove multiple items from a list at the same time by index in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
> a = ["a","b","c","d","e"] 
> Enum.reject_multiple(a,[1,3])
["a", "c", "e"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clearest way I can think would be to include indices and reject the desired items.

```rb
rejected_indices = MapSet.new([1, 3])

["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
|> Stream.with_index()
|> Stream.reject(fn {_item, index} -> index in rejected_indices end)
|> Enum.map(&elem(&1, 0))
#=> ["a", "c", "e"]
```

Comment: _Sidenote:_ by wrapping this in macro, one might make `index in rejected_indices` to be a guard expression, which might increase the performance, see my answer for details. And yes, I understand, that this is a premature optimization not needed in 99% of cases :)

Answer (score 0):

While the proper way to go is definitely provided by @BrettBeatty, I’d like to post the example of how it might be achieved with a single pass through the list, using some metaprogramming magic. Just for the sake of example.

```rb
defmodule MyEnum do
  defmacro decimate(list, indices) do
    quote do
      unquote(list)
      |> Enum.reduce({0, []}, fn
        _, {i, acc} when i in unquote(indices) -> {i + 1, acc}
        e, {i, acc} -> {i + 1, [e | acc]}
      end)
      |> elem(1)
      |> Enum.reverse()
    end
  end
end

require MyEnum
MyEnum.decimate(~w[a b c d e], [1, 3])
#⇒ ["a", "c", "e"]
```

Macro is needed for an ability to put `indices` in guard.